# asp.net mvc Ajax.Actionlink routeValues as nested object

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My ActionLink with routeValues: lld.

```
                        @Html.Raw(@Ajax.ActionLink(
                                              linkText: "[replacetext]",
                                              actionName: "StartAndCreateNewDetail",
                                              controllerName: "PpLd",
                                              routeValues: lld,
                                              ajaxOptions: new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "tblProgressbarAndAction" }
                            ).ToHtmlString().Replace("[replacetext]", "<span id='" + @btnStart + "' class='glyphicon glyphicon-play'></span>"))
```

lld is an object from typ:

```
public class Lld
{
    public LE le { get; set; }

    public List<LEDETAIL> lstLEDETAIL { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

    public long LeErbId { get; set; }
}
```

Controller method:

```
public ActionResult StartAndCreateNewDetail(Lld lld){

  le = lld.le; // is null
  lstLEDETAIL lstDe = lld.lstLEDETAIL; // is null
  ReleaseDate rd = lld.RealeseDate; // is not null
  LeErbId leerbid = lld.LeErbId; // is not null

}
```

Why lld.le and lld.lstLEDETAIL are null?

Comment: What HTML does that produce? I feel like using `Raw` and `Replace` is a very bad idea.

Comment: Because you cannot pass properties of a model which are complex objects or collections as route values - look at the html your generating to understand - it will include `le=yourAssembly.LE` and `lstLEDETAIL=System.Collections.Generic.List[LEDETAIL]`

Comment: Thank you Stephen. I have it supposed.
"...  any properties which are complex objects or collections will cause binding to fail ..."